# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I tried to to load a simple example of spring mvc with a simple jsp but failed with the following error: ***No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp]***
I'm using Spring 3.2.2.
I really appreciate your help here. 
I tried several thing but still it seems that I can not map my jsp page in the controller.

**web.xml** looks like that:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
               xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**HelloWeb-servlet.xml** looks like that:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorial.spring" />

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

**HelloControll.class** looks like that:

```
package com.tutorial.spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
  @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
  public String printHello(ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

    return "hello";
  }
}
```

Comment: How have you used your contextConfigLocation in your web.xml to load the Spring XML file?

Answer (score 1):

Correct URL to hit your `printHello` handler method is

```
/HelloWeb/hello.jsp
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. foolish mistake.
I named my jsp "Hello.jsp" with capital 'H' and returned in my controller 'hello' with lower case.

Just changed my jsp page to be "hello.jsp".

thanks for your help.

Comment: Please accept  your answer. It will help people like me to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify web.xml like this

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Try to access /**YourAppName**/hello. Then Spring-MVC will trigger the method `printHello()` . Then return the jsp view in /WEB-INF/jsp/.

Comment: thanks, I tried that and I got "HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWeb/hello.jsp" error in browser and no special error in catalina log.

Comment: also the browser error said: 
"description The requested resource is not available." even though it is available.
Did I missed something here ?

Comment: what's your accessed URL? Please Post that.

Comment: use this URL localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello, spring-mvc return the jsp view "hello.jsp" automaicly

Answer (score 0):

The dispatcher servlet have to map the correct main route:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that and I got "HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWeb/hello.jsp" error in browser and no special error in catalina log.
Is there a way to debug it ?

Comment: do u know how can I debug it?

Comment: You are mapping /HelloWeb/hello not /HelloWeb/hello.jsp.
Try add the requestMapping value in the method you can do this: 
``@Controller 
public class HelloController { 

 @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method= RequestMethod.GET)
 public String printHello(ModelMap modelMap) { ``

so now you are mapping **/HelloWeb/hello**, or you can do:

``@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/hello") 
public class HelloController { 

 @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET) 
 public String printHello(ModelMap modelMap) { ``

and you are now mapping **/HelloWeb/hello/**

Comment: Hi Emanuele,
I tried them both and I got the following exception in catalina log:
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/Hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'.
Even though, i got a message that HelloWeb is deploying.

Comment: Have you tried to request the uri /HelloWeb/hello (first case) or /HelloWeb/hello/ (second case)?

Answer (score 0):

move jsp file to right place as defined in servlet

**/WEB-INF/jsp/**

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL is `http://localhost:8080/hello`, without "/HelloWeb"